# reload page with changed querystring

Tags: php, sql, query-string

I have a page with php query results in a table. Now I want to click on a table column name to sort it on that. So what I want to do is reload the page with the same querystring but change one parameter ("&orderby=name").

The only way I can think of is to get the query with $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; and then search and replace the one parameter with regular expressions. And then use that to reload the page by clicking a link.

But there has to be some easier way, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace the $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] and use that as an argument but a more elegant solution would be something like:

```
$params = $_GET;
$params['orderby'] = 'column';
$query = http_build_query($params);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can rebuild the query string from $_GET. just loop over it and add new variables to a string. then a simple conditional can swap any of them out.

Comment: aaah yes that is an array right... thanks! (why does i have to wait 12 minutes to accept this as answer..)